# Where is the used memory in Task Manager & Resource Monitor coming from?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

On a Windows 7, the working set memory usage plus private memory does not add up to the total used memory in Task Manager and Windows 7 Resource Monitor.

How do you find out where the used memory is coming from?
The cached memory can't be part of it because sometimes the total cache is greater than the total in use. The commit memory plus the working set also doesn't add up to the total in use - but even that shouldn't be significant if it did, since commit is virtual.

Comment: users often forget the pool memory (paged and non paged). Look at your values.

Answer (score 2):

The terms used in the different Windows tools do not always have the same meaning.
I suggest watching [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL405) and [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL406) for an overview of the different categories.

You are confounding different categories of memory. The working set is the amount of physical memory the process is using. This can be private or shareable. The private memory can be either in physical memory or pagefile.

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229) and [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533) can be used to investigate further.